# AutoCompleteTextView in android using Firebase and Filterable inteface

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, autocompletetextview

I am working on an android app where I am going to store school names under one node for e.g. schools. I want to implement Autocomplete functionality for the schoolnames, .i.e when user starts typing school name he/she will see the schoolnames starting/matching the particular condition(top 5 records matching the condition can be shown). Assume that each schoolname is a String.

```
public class SchoolsAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 10;
    private Context mContext;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    private List<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();
    public SchoolsAutoCompleteAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef=database.getReference("mschools");
        schools=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return schools.size();
    }

    @Override
    public School getItem(int position) {
        return schools.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.school_autocomplete_list_row, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_email)).setText(getItem(position).getEmail());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_name)).setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    schools = findSchools(constraint.toString());
                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = schools;
                    filterResults.count = schools.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
    private List<School> findSchools(String studentUsername)  {
        final List<School> schools=new ArrayList<>();
        Query abc= myRef.orderByChild("schoolname").startAt(studentUsername).endAt(studentUsername+"\uf8ff").limitToFirst(5);
        abc.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //schools.add(childDataSnapshot.getValue(School.class));
                    School s=childDataSnapshot.getValue(School.class);
                    schools.add(new School(s.getEmail(),s.getName()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return schools;
    }
}
```

As per the code `return schools` line is executing before the onDataChange method as firebase executes asynchronously .So it is returning empty record.
Some relational database can be used to implement this functionality, but I don't want to add extra database to implement just this functionality. If I keep breakpoint at `return schools;` line, I am able to see the result. Can I implement this scenario using Firebase or am I missing something?